# Creating a single bar chart in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to draw a bar graph like shown below in R

[image]

This is created from data frame like

```
X1   X2  X3
No   No  No
Yes  No  Yes
Yes  Yes Yes

36% = total no of yes in X1
64% = (total no of yes in X2+total no of yes in X3)
```

Please bear with me and comment if the question is not clear.

Comment: it will be 33 & 67 % :)

Comment: graph is just for representation, actual percentages may vary.

Comment: check out the package `ggplot2`, as I see it you'll need to use `geom_bar` and `geom_text` and set it as stacked

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper how to do with ggplot2 and geom_bar can you please little bit elaborate.

Comment: Whoever voting it negatively please mention the reasons if possible so that I can improve my questions next time

Answer (score 1):

A direct way to get that is to just plot the polygons and add the text.

```
Proportion1 = 0.36
Proportion2 = 0.64

plot(NULL, xlim=c(0,1), ylim=c(0,1), xaxt="n", yaxt="n",
    xlab="", ylab="", bty='n')
polygon(c(0,Proportion1,Proportion1,0), c(0.4,0.4,0.6,0.6), col="blue")
polygon(c(Proportion1,1,1,Proportion1), c(0.4,0.4,0.6,0.6), col="green")
text(c(Proportion1/2, Proportion2/2 + Proportion1), c(0.5,0.5), 
    c(paste0(100*Proportion1, "%"), paste0(100*Proportion2, "%")), 
    col="white", cex=1.5)
```

[image: One Bar]